How to create enough plot events to show more of a setting
I have an adventuring party that's going in a dungeon. The dungeon is why I wanted to write this story, because I have some interesting ideas for its backstory. It'll have a reveal at the end that will hopefully be built up to. I want to have more events so that the story is longer and I have more time to show around the dungeon itself, but it feels like I'm just adding, not weaving the events. It's almost like I'm just stacking blocks when I want to make them a web of interconnected events, and the events I add don't come naturally from the story beforehand.
I've seen in other answers that you should think of what your character is going to do and build the plot from there. That might solve what the party members are going to do, but then how do I figure out what challenges they're going to face next? I feel like the setting is so endless that it doesn't have anything it "should" respond with, unlike the characters.
I know there also should be conflict between the party members, but can they replace the external, dungeon-side conflict? Can I really just make them stroll around the dungeon, arguing against each other, noticing bits and details about the rooms they're in while nothing really happens with the dungeon itself? Even so, how would I make the arguments last long enough to show what I want?
So what I'm struggling with is: how do I naturally derive enough action or external events to go around and showcase the dungeon?

It seems to me that you are limited by the idea that locations must be shown to the reader through some significant event that takes place there and that drives the plot forward, for example an opponent that is overcome or a mystery that is uncovered etc.
There are other types of stories, though. Explorer's tales, for example, in which the viewpoint character walks around a location and describes what he sees, such as H. P. Lovecraft's At the Mountains of Madness (in which a scientific expedition explores an ancient city in Antarctica) or Stanisław Lem's Eden (in which astronauts explore an alien city).
I don't see why your protagnists cannot just walk around your dungeon and explore it.
Of course this may become boring if you just show an endless series of rooms full of sarcophagi and inscriptions. Many role playing games are repetitive and boring in this way. In Lovecraft's tale there are no events over long stretches of the narrative – no fights or conflicts –, but there is a continual build-up of dread as the scientists slowly begin to understand the nature of the evil that resides in the Antarctic city. In Lem's tale there are no events during much of the exploration, either, but the scientists slowly begin to understand the dystopic nature of the alien society they are observing.
Both stories provide their readers with an intellectual journey of discovery and the emotions – horror and scepticism, respectively – that come with the understanding they provide. In the same way, you can use the rooms and inventory of your dungeon to tell an intellectual tale of understanding. Whether that tale is intriguing or boring for your readers will depend on the tale that you tell and how you narrate its discovery.

Thank you! This helps a lot. I've read At the Mountains of Madness before, and noticed there's not much focus on the characters. Would you say that also concentrating on character conflict takes away from the horror atmosphere of this exploration / discovery genre, or is it just Lovecraft's choice?

@Ikoistre I'd say that much of the horror in the Lovecraft type of tales is an effect of the protagonist being both an "everyman", a stand-in for the reader, without much of a personality as well as being more of a passive (experiencing) victim than a proactive (problem-solving and goal-oriented) hero. In grimdark fantasy, for example, the hero would overcome the monsters that live in the Mountains of Madness. He might get broken by the experience, but he would survive, grimmer than before.
